# Is this a right solution?

Tags: linear-algebra

This is a question in my mock math test. On the square box is the question and below is the answer. 
I think that the solution below is wrong, because the 2nd equation should be x1+2x2+2x3 instead of x1+2x2 +2x3.

But if I assume that the equation is correct, I still do not know how do you solve the equation to generate the solution. I thought that the solution for Ax=b is p+nullA, in this case p is (-1 3/2 0) but I don't know what is the A in this case to calculate the null of it, therefore I also do not understand the meaning of span(1 -1 1). 
Can anyone explain to me about this answer? 
Many thanks.

[image: This is the question]

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1):

First, subtract the third equation from the second one like as follows:
$$(x_1+2x_2+2x_3)-(2x_2+2x_3)=2-3 \\ x_1=-1$$
Then,we can find $x_2$ by replacing $x_1$ in the first equation:
$$2x_1+2x_2=1 \\ 2(-1)+2x_2=1 \\ 2x_2-2=1 \\ 2x_2=1+2=3 \\ x_2= \frac 3 2$$
Finally, using any of the second or the third equation will help in finding $x_3$:
$$2x_2+2x_3=3 \\ 2 \left( \frac 3 2 \right)+2x_3=3 \\ 2x_3=3-3=0 \\ x_3=0$$
That's how you solve the equation, but you asked what "span" means, so I hope you find what you are looking for on this Wikipedia article: [Linear span](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_span)